# Sitecore 10.3 ASP.NET Core headless - can Glass Mapper still be used?

Tags: asp.net-core, sitecore, glass-mapper

Can Glass Mapper still be used with the Sitecore 10 ASP.NET Core headless approach?

Glass Mapper docs appear to be leading to 404's so I'm unsure if this is supported or not. If you have had any experience with this please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried this one https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glass.Mapper.Sc.103.Core yet?